# Is $\log^* (n+1)^{n+2} \in O(\log^* n)$?

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics, computational-complexity

I would like to know if $\log^* (n+1)^{n+2} \in O(\log^* n)$, where $\log^*$ is the [iterated logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm).

I tried doing:

$ \log^* (n+1)^{n+2} =\\ 
\log^{*}(\log(n+1)^{n+2})-1 =\\
\log^{*}((n+2) \cdot \log(n+1))-1 =\\
\log^{*}(\log((n+2)\cdot \log (n+1)))-2 =\\
\log^{*}(\log(n+2) + \log\log (n+1))-2 =\\
\log^{*}(O(\log n))-2 =\\
O(\log^{*}n)$

...but:

1. I'm not sure the operations are correct (probably, they are not).
2. <s>I don't know how to prove O(\log^{*-1}n) = O(\log^* n)</s>.